# Adding Captcha without accessing ASP

Tags: forms, validation, captcha, recaptcha

A client would like us to add a Captcha to their form at http://www.vilaswi.com/contact/. However, they use a 3rd party to run their authentication through http://www.innline.com/mailforms/vilasform/Record.asp so the form data displayed to the user is really the only thing I have control over. It looks like I can't add the Google reCaptcha PHP to the form as the action is already specified (see below).

```
<form action="http://www.innline.com/mailforms/vilasform/Record.asp" method="post" name="frmInfo" id="frmInfo" onsubmit="return validateForm()" class="contactform">
```

Google recommends download verify.php and adding that to the action. Is there another method I could use?

I have tried the honey pot method and that has not curbed the amount of spam submitted.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: No. Contact the other site and tell them to verify the captcha, or your honeypots :)

Comment: I talked to them this week and they seem to think that adding a simple form field like 3+3 and the entry field would have to be 6. Would this not help? Or if they're bypassing the honeypot, then maybe this wouldn't be enough security? Just curious before I get on their case again :).